# Correct way to use es6 modularity with gulp + babelify + browserify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I have to use es6 modularity for my next project, the tools used for building the es6 modularity have been finalised to be gulp,babelify & browserify, I am confused because I am new to all three,& how they work to create es6 modularity. relevant part of my gulp file is

```
function bundle_js(bundler) {
return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    // capture sourcemaps from transforms
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
  }

// Without watchify
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var bundler = browserify('app.js', { debug: true }).transform(babelify, {/* options */ })

    return bundle_js(bundler)
})
```

I want to ask

1. which file should i reference in index.html, app.js or dist/app.min.js
2. there are other js files also in es6 with module export function in js/*js 
   folder, does babelify/browserify uses only entry js file (app.js) or all the src files (js/*js ) for  modularity?

Comment: 1. `dist/app.min.js`
2. Only one entry file. You're referencing your modules in the entry file and browserify picks all the stuff up and combines it to your out file (`dist/app.min.js`)

Comment: thanks, can i use import/export in other js file, plus what do you exactly mean when you say "You're referencing your modules in the entry file" , can I not use import in other js file (only export modules?) or do you mean <script src ""> thing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You do everything in your javascript, except for adding `dist/app.min.js` to your `index.html`. Given a simple structure, `A`, `B`, `C` - where `A` references `B`, you can reference `C` in `B` and it will be compiled into your `dist/app.min.js`. You can also use node modules and they will be added to `dist/app.min.js`, so no need for bower or directly including libraries in your `index.html`.

Comment: so no need to <script src ""> other js files in index.html or app.js? because my confusion is I think browserify will bundle app.js in dist/app.min.js & other relevant files would be in js/*js folder, & they will be referenced in app.js like "import { BOARD_PADDING, BOARD_SIZE } from './js/board';" these relative paths will be taken care of by browserify?

Comment: Yes. In your `app.js` you have all those require and imports and whatsoever, but browserify will combine them for you and put everything in your out file `dist/app.min.js`. One single big file with all your code, libraries and whatever you referenced in your javascript(s).

Comment: also if you could point me to some tutorial of github implimentation with file folder structure, this would greatly help

Comment: Try https://github.com/mdix/es6-babel-browserify-karma-boilerplate and ignore the `karma` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113336/discussion-between-carelesslychoosy-and-marc-dix).